# Show active dialog form even main program window is not active

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I need to show input dialog form of program that main form dialog is minimised in tray. Currently I have input dialog form shown on the desktop, but when this form shown for the first time it is inactive. To make this dialog active I do :

```
BOOL CDialogExInput::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    this->SetWindowPos(&this->wndTop,1000,1000,1000,1000,SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE);
    return true;
}
```

But looks this has no influence since even dialog form size is not changed. Maybe this is not right place to make `SetWindowPos` ?

UPT:

Trying to focus my question. Let's auume I have simple dialog based application. Let's run it and deactivate (click mouse on any other window). I need on timer event make my dialog application form active (in keyboard input focus).
`SetWindowPos` and `SetFocus` doesn't help.

```
// focusDlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "focus.h"
#include "focusDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

#define ID_TIMER_1 100
// CfocusDlg dialog




CfocusDlg::CfocusDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CfocusDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CfocusDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CfocusDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_TIMER()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &CfocusDlg::OnBnClickedOk)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CfocusDlg message handlers

BOOL CfocusDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();



    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    SetTimer(ID_TIMER_1,3000,NULL);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CfocusDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CfocusDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}

void CfocusDlg::OnTimer(UINT)
{
    //MessageBox(L"Time");
    this->SetWindowPos(&this->wndTop,1000,1000,1000,1000,SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE);// | SWP_SHOWWINDOW );
    this->SetFocus();
}



void CfocusDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`OnInitDialog()` is exactly the right place where you can modify the dialog window; when the framework calls this function, the dialog box window already exists but is not yet visible.

If you want the window to be moved and resized you mustn't specify the `SWP_NOSIZE` nor the `SWP_NOMOVE` flags during the call of `SetWindowPos`.

Comment: Yes exactly, windows resized when I called this->SetWindowPos(&this->wndTop,1000,1000,1000,1000,SWP_SHOWWINDOW); But how to make this window active?

Comment: You cannot make the dialog visible in OnInitDialog. This function is called only once during `DoModal`. I'm not quite sure how your program is working, maybe you should elaborate this a bit in your question.